Intercept calibration in logistic hierarchical regression model
i am following Debray et al. 2013 (A framework for developing, implementing, and evaluating clinical prediction models in an individual participant data meta-analysis) to estimate a risk prediction model. I have ~40 diagnostic studies and I estimate a hierarchical logistic regression with random intercepts and random slopes for a continuous, mean scaled predictor in Stan.
I have now trouble understanding the logic behind the intercept calculation for application of the model in a population where the overall prevalence is known (section 2.2.3). Debray et al. suggest to calculate the appropriate intercept by $\alpha = \ln(\frac{prev_n}{1-prev_n})$, with $prev_n$ being the prevalence in the new population (p.6). For example, assuming a prevalence of 5% this results in an intercept of -2.944.
However, when i compare this to my actual intercepts in the risk model, i find that studies with similar intercepts have ~10% prevalence. Shouldn't I get an intercept more like the studies with a 5% prevalence? It seems to me that the calculated intercept $\alpha$ is too large. I think this is because the intercepts estimated in the random effects model does not reflect the overall prevalence, but rather the risk of somebody with a mean predictor score?
Any insight would be appreciated.
EDIT:
the risk model is this, with ab being study-specific intercepts and slopes. mean_ab and sigma_ab are their means and covariance matrix.
data{
  int n_rows;
  int n_studies;
  int study_id[n_rows];
  real cont_predictor[n_rows];
  int cases[n_rows];
  int n[n_rows];
}

parameters{
  matrix[2,n_studies] ab;
  
  vector[2] mean_ab;
  cov_matrix[2] sigma_ab;
}

model{
  
  for (i in 1:n_studies){
    ab[,i] ~ multi_normal(mean_ab, sigma_ab);
  }
  
  for (i in 1:n_rows){
    cases[i] ~ binomial_logit(n[i], ab[1,study_id[i]] + ab[2,study_id[i]] * cont_predictor[i]);
  }
}

These are the results (truncated some):
Inference for Stan model: anon_model.
4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1; 
post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.

                  mean se_mean   sd     2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5% n_eff Rhat
ab[1,1]          -4.40    0.01 0.60    -5.66    -4.79    -4.37    -3.99    -3.35  4469    1
ab[1,2]          -3.08    0.01 0.44    -3.99    -3.38    -3.06    -2.77    -2.25  4571    1
...
ab[2,1]           0.35    0.00 0.06     0.24     0.31     0.35     0.39     0.47  4331    1
...
ab[2,41]          0.33    0.00 0.06     0.22     0.28     0.32     0.37     0.45  4601    1
mean_ab[1]       -2.92    0.00 0.24    -3.40    -3.07    -2.92    -2.76    -2.48  5126    1
mean_ab[2]        0.32    0.00 0.02     0.28     0.31     0.32     0.34     0.36  3185    1
sigma_ab[1,1]     1.87    0.01 0.55     1.06     1.48     1.78     2.17     3.20  3501    1
sigma_ab[1,2]    -0.03    0.00 0.03    -0.11    -0.05    -0.03    -0.01     0.02  2319    1
sigma_ab[2,1]    -0.03    0.00 0.03    -0.11    -0.05    -0.03    -0.01     0.02  2319    1
sigma_ab[2,2]     0.01    0.00 0.00     0.01     0.01     0.01     0.01     0.02  2304    1

And this is the relevant section of Debray et al. I'd like to apply:


I think it might be useful to include whatever code or priors you used to specify your model, otherwise it will be impossible to say. If you set a prior in or your model to be one value and the data overwhelmingly shows that the estimated parameter is something entirely different, then this likely means that either the sample has some very specific attributes that perhaps you didn't expect, the model is mis-specified in some way, or that the prior you used may not accurately reflect the population.

I take from Debray et al. that at this step i just calculate a new intercept based on a expectation of prevalence in the population of interest (and not actual data)?

I'm still confused by this new edit. It says you fit the model with Stan, but now you have a model estimated by lme4. Where is your Stan model? And does it include explicitly specified priors? Please show those in your question.

sorry, my bad. I added the Stan model and results. There are no specific priors in there.

If you know what other studies say in terms of their coefficients (e.g. the intercept), then why not add that into the Stan code? That in my opinion is the point of Bayes...you're incorporating past information into the model. Using the default priors can lend to poor model interpretation.

I don't know the appropriate intercept, but rather the overall prevalence.
